# Could not find uniform_notifier-1.13.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am facing issues while deploying on CI in uniform_notifier. I thought maybe the ruby version is not compatible with the latest version of the uniform_notifier. I am using bullet gem and a uniform_notifier is a dependency of it.

Initially, bullet and uniform notifier version were

```
bullet (6.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      uniform_notifier (~> 1.11)
```

I tried to downgrade bullet & uniform notified to 1.10.0 but it didn't work for me

```
bullet (5.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      uniform_notifier (~> 1.10.0)
```

CI ruby version: 2.4.2
Rails; 5.2.0

```
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find uniform_notifier-1.13.0 in any of the sources
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:91:in `block in materialize'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Reskinning_test/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Reskinning_test/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Reskinning_test/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/var/lib/jenkins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/bin/rake:23:in `<main>
```

**Jenkins**

```
cat config/database.yml
gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc && bundle install
echo USER=$USER && ruby --version && which ruby && which bundle 
cp dotenv.template .env
sed -i -e 's/DB_USER=user/DB_USER=username/g' ./.env
sed -i -e 's/DB_PASSWORD=password/DB_PASSWORD=password/g' ./.env
EXECUTOR_NUMBER=10
export RAILS_ENV=test
DB_HOST=localhost rake db:test:load_structure --trace

rspec spec/

rake jasmine:ci
```

Comment: The gem version [does exist](https://rubygems.org/gems/uniform_notifier/versions/1.13.0), and is only dependant on ruby `>= 2.3`, so that shouldn't be an issue. To be clear, are you saying that the installation works fine locally but fails on CI?

Comment: @TomLord Yes in local I tried with the same version of ruby, rails, bullet, and uniform_notifier and I don't get any issue. Whereas in Ci I am facing this issue

Comment: ALso, I.13.0 & 1.10.0 do exist in uniform_notifier.

Comment: It actually looks as though the error isn't "couldn't install the gem", but rather, that your Jenkins config is trying to run the application *before updating the dependencies*?? Are you trying to run something like `rspec` *before* running `bundle`, in CI? If you ssh to the machine and run `bundle` manually, does that work?

Comment: @TomLord I don't think so because for other gems it hasn't gave any error. Also, I have updated the CI conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by upgrading the ruby version in the CI(Jenkins) from ruby-2.4.2 to Ruby-2.5.3